Can Google Keep's checklist suggestions be disabled?
First of all, I have searched for this issue already and found this post. However the advice to change the default notes and list provider to something other than google keep did not work for me.  So I am opening a new question because of that.  These suggestions are completely irrelevent to me and cause me to be annoyed, which decreases productivity and overall satisfaction.  I can't see how there is any actual gain from these suggestions in the first place, because the probability that one of these suggestions was exactly what I was looking for is probably one in about a million.  As you can see they aren't even closely related to what my notes are about.

FWIW, the asker of the linked question also stated that the answer didn't work, so I don't know if there's any working solutions for now.

Finally, suggestions that are tailored to my activity!
I saw that post too but sadly its a no go.  I'm not retraining my brain to put a space in front of every thing I type, and the uBlock filter only works on the web, not the app.  I was hoping for a more advanced tweak which is why I am posting this here and not reddit.
